# How to automate exporting specific sheet (i.e "SheetA") as a PDF to Google Drive?

Tags: pdf, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-macros

I create an advanced price calculator and its result located on another sheet called "SheetA".
Each time I need to select my printable design area in SheetA and then manually export it as a PDF. 
I am trying to automate it by macro and when I run the macro it exports SheetA as a pdf to my Google Drive. 
Could you please help me?

Comment: Please add the code of your macro you have so far

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a full snippet for export a sheet to another file https://github.com/contributorpw/google-apps-script-snippets/tree/master/snippets/standalone_export-spreadsheet-to

If you need to export a sheet 'SHEET 1' from the spreadsheet '****' to file you have to

```
function runSheet() {
  var spec = ['SHEET 1'];

  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(
    '****'
  ).copy('tmp');

  spec.forEach(function(sheetName) {
    var dr = spreadsheet.getSheetByName(sheetName).getDataRange();
    dr.setValues(dr.getValues());
  });
  spreadsheet.getSheets().forEach(function(sheet) {
    if (spec.indexOf(sheet.getName()) < 0) spreadsheet.deleteSheet(sheet);
  });
  var spreadsheetId = spreadsheet.getId();
  var file = exportSpreadsheetToFile_(spreadsheetId, 'xlsx');
  DriveApp.getFileById(spreadsheetId).setTrashed(true);
  return file;
}
```

The full listing of `exportSpreadsheetToFile_` by the link above.